# JMeter - Issues with Image Upload for API Request. Recording doesn't work

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

1. If I upload an image on Postman using only binary option it works. If I use form-data to upload a file on Postman the image file gets corrupted with unnecessary appended info. So I tried to record JMeter script while uploading image on Postman using binary option. But the image size grew from 279kb to 509kb and I got a corrupt image. It's only 279kb when I send on Postman without recording. See pictures below.
2. If I use the "Files Upload" tab on JMeter HTTP Request, it appends info as below making the image file corrupt. The JAVA implementation on Advanced tab doesn't work either.
   --WNAkrdOzMmE0iZxPNbdHVVPxuBwgUX
   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="source"; filename="fileupload.jpg"
   Content-Type: image/jpeg

Can someone please provide me Groovy or BeanShell code to upload multiple image files one by one? Or, if there is a way to capture the traffic properly without the image file getting corrupt with additional data, please let me know and I can try. Thanks.
[image: Same picture but bigger size when recording in JMeter]

[image: Original size when sending only from Postman using binary option]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`binary` file upload means that the file is being send as the [HTTP Post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request body

JMeter's equivalent configuration would be:

1. Switch to the Files Upload tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler
2. Provide full or relative path to the file you want to upload
3. Other fields should remain intact

[image]

More information: [JMeter Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-testing)